# Android Wear Sign In to Parse.com

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, nsuserdefaults, wear-os

I have an app on iPhone and the Apple Watch that uses Parse.com. On iOS I use NSUserDefaults and App Groups to sign the user in on Apple Watch with the same account as their iPhone.

I am now working on this app for Android and would like to do the same. I do not know how I should share the username and password string with the Android Wear device.

What should I be using? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With Android Wear the watch OS doesn't directly access internet services.  You have to create a communications interface between the phone and watch apps and make requests from the watch to the phone to call Parse and the same goes for incoming events, the phone receives them and you pass them to the watch.  Recommend reading the Google Data API docs
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html